# How to parse XML using XmlPullParser

Tags: java, xml, xmlpullparser

I want to use the Java XmlPullParser to parse an XML file like this:

```
<start>
    <tag1> text1 </tag1>
    <tag2> 
        <tag3>text3</tag3>
        <tag1>text4</tag1>
    </tag2>
    <tag4> text5</tag4>
</start>
```

I want only `<tag1> text1 </tag1>` as the result. My current method produces both `<tag1> text1 </tag1>` and `<tag1>text4<tag1/>`. What else must I do?

**Edit:**

I am getting the XML in `String` format. I want to parse it using `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;`.

Comment: In the future, if you have a specific requirement (including but not limited to a particular parser), please mention it in the first draft of your question.

Answer (score 9):

You could also just use the `javax.xml.xpath` APIs:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class XPathDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();
        InputSource xml = new InputSource(new FileReader("input.xml"));
        Node result = (Node) xpath.evaluate("/tag1", xml, XPathConstants.NODE);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Everyone has thier own preferences for XML processing in Java and my preference is to use [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/) when dealing with XML in Java because I find it easier to use that straight xpath.

Comment: I would still use JAXB with the only difference being that I would use a transform to save the xml string as an xml file then unmarshall the file into a Java object using JAXB and then get what I wanted from the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using [Java Xpath API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

try to use dom4j library

```
    InputStream is = FileUtils.class.getResourceAsStream(filepath);
    SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
    org.dom4j.Document doc = reader.read(is);
    is.close();
    Element content = doc.getRootElement();
    List<Element> els = content.elements("elemeNtname");
```

after this in method you will get  in els list all the elements in xml file with name "elemeNtname".